# Python: Usage of Variables and their difference ("a, b = 0, 1" VS "a = 0", "b = 1")

Tags: python, variables, fibonacci

I was looking at the Python Manual and found this snippet for a Fibonacci-Number generator:

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()
```

The output is dependent on n and returns a valid Fibonacci sequence.

If you remodel this to use the variables "a" and "b" seperately like so:

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a = b
        b = a+b
    print()
```

then it will print a number sequence that increments by the power of 2 (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on).

So I was wondering why that happens? What is the actual difference between the two uses of variables?

Comment: Yes. It's a duplicate. Didn't find the other entry with the search function prior to creating this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doing:

`a, b = b, a+b`

is equivalent to:

```
temp = a
a = b
b += temp
```

It lets you simultaneously do two calculations without the need of an intermediate/temporary variable.

The difference is that in your second piece of code, when you do the second line `b = a+b`, you have already modifed `a` in the previous line which is **not** the same as the first piece of code.

#### Examples

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 3
>>> a,b
2 3
>>> a,b = b,a
>>> a,b
3 2
```

On the other hand, if you use the second approach shown in your question:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 3
>>> a,b
2 3
>>> a = b
>>> b = a
>>> a,b
3 3
```

Comment: @waffl3head, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you

Comment: Done. Wasn't able to do it because of the short timespan between posting the question and your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
    a, b = b, a+b
```

the right-hand expressions are evaluated first, and their results are assigned to `a` and `b`. This is similar to the following:

```
    _new_a = b
    _new_b = a+b
    a = _new_a
    b = _new_b
```

On the other hand, in

```
    a = b
    b = a+b
```

you are modifying `a` before adding it to `b`. This is equivalent to

```
    a, b = b, b+b
```

which explains where the powers of two are coming from.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.